# where are translations of standard items in iOS UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, localization, uitabbarcontroller

In a Tab Bar View Controller I use the Apple Bar Button Icon 'Favorites'.
When I run the App on my iPhone with the locale setting 'Germany' I expect 'Favorites' to be translated into german like it's working in the iBooks App. But this is not the case. Do I have to make some extra adjustments in Xcode for that?

Thanks 
Martin

Comment: Did you add german as an support language to your project ?

Comment: No, I can't. When I go to Project -> Info there is no entry Localization. When I go to Editor -> Add Localization everything is gray and not choosable. The only thing I can do is to go in the info.plist and change the language from English to German.

Comment: To get the localization to work you should at German to the localizations list.

Comment: Ok, I found it! Didn't know how to switch between Target and Project..